# ¿Como pasar datos de una api a otra pagina y recibirlos para despues renderizar en pantalla?

Tags: flutter

No supe como poner un titulo mejor a la pregunta.....
tengo un carrusel de imagenes de la api rick y morty, esta es la url https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character.
quiero que al dar click en una de esas imagenes me lleve a una pagina donde se muestre el resto de informacion, aqui el modelo para ser mas especifico.

```
class DataApi {
  String image;
  String name;
  String state;
  String gender;

  DataApi({
    required this.image,
    required this.name,
    required this.state,
    required this.gender,
  });

  factory DataApi.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return DataApi(
      image: json['image'],
      name: json['name'],
      state: json['status'],
      gender: json['species'],
    );
    /*name: json["name"],
      state: json["status"],
      gender: json["species"]*/

    //List? get results => null;
  }
}
```

entonces lo que hice fue envolver el container de la imagen con un GestureDetector.

```
return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(
              context,
              '/details',
              arguments: snapshot.data![index],
            );
          },
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(9.0)),
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: NetworkImage(snapshot.data![index].image),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
```

no se si lo estoy haciendo bien(o como hacerlo) porque debo pasar como argumento el resto de la informacion para luego recibirla en otro screen y renderizarla.que este caso estarian dentro de text widgets

Comment: lo que hize para resolverlo fue pasando los parametros entre constructores

Comment: lo hiciste muy desorganizado ,primero tienes que determinar la api poner un fetch y imprimir el resultado en otro punto en mi caso estoy desarrollando una apk todo se usa dentro de {{ contenido que sera impreso }}
pero ese contenido debes sacarlo de la appi

Comment: me alegra que lo resolvieras. Por favor añade una respuesta detallada con lo que hiciste para que si otros usuarios se encuentran con un problema similar, esta publicación les sirva de ayuda y guía.